# Ошибка ключа VKSDK опубликованного в маркете приложения

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, android-vksdk

В моем приложении есть интеграция с VKSDK. Все работает когда компилишь с компа. А вот когда закидываешь APK в google play и он опубликовался, то выясняется, что при авторизации доступа к ключу ВК пишет ошибку типа чет там неправильно. Но опять же повторюсь, что когда запускаешь с компа, то все норм. Что это может быть?

Comment: Думаю, если бы Вы чуть по-подробнее рассказали бы про «типа чет там неправильно», то решение Вашего вопроса ускорилось бы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С компа вы запускаете приложение подписанное debug ключом по умолчанию. SHA-1 именно этого, дебажного, ключа у вас и прописано в настройках приложения на сайте  ВК.

В маркет же вы должны выкладывать приложение подписанное релизным ключом. Т.е. вам надо в настройках приложения на сайте vk.com добавить SHA-1 релизного ключа. Т.е. их там два должно быть - для релизного и для дебажного

Получить отпечаток ключа можно по разному. [В доке это описано](https://vk.com/dev/android_sdk). Вот простейший вариант, если уже подключено SDK в проект:

```
String[] fingerprints = VKUtil.getCertificateFingerprint(this, this.getPackageName());
```

Comment: Но там же только для одного ключа есть графа: "Отпечаток сертификата для Android"???

Comment: @sviter-pro, там также есть кнопка типа "добавить ещё один". Вообще их кол-во неограничено

Comment: Я понял...а где взять SHA-1 для релизного? Он такой же какой и дебажный?

Comment: Его где-то в google play брать надо?

Comment: @sviter-pro, его надо получать так же, как и дебажный. Способов несколько. Вот, например, [способ из доки в VKSDK](https://vk.com/dev/android_sdk), там, кстати и про релизный ключ написано. Почитайте - сразу много вопросов отпадёт : `String[] fingerprints = VKUtil.getCertificateFingerprint(this, this.getPackageName());`

Comment: попробывал..сработало....но он пишет точно такой же кокой у меня уже стоит...Мне их два писать?

Comment: Не может быть такой же. Вы это точно на релизной сборке проверили?

Comment: не уверен...просто добавил этот код в свой код и запустил приложение....а в логкате нашол его.... а как в релизную сборку засунуть его?

Comment: @sviter-pro, то что вы описали - это дебажная сборка приложения. Вам надо подписать APK релизным ключом, запустить его и смотреть в логи.

Comment: Как это сделать не подскажите?

Comment: @sviter-pro, по идее, если вы в манифесте, в тег application добавите  `android:debugable="true"`, создадите подписанную релизным ключом apk-шку и запустите её на телефоне и подключите телефон к компу и запустите студии и откроете logcat то всё выведется стандартым способом. Главное помнить, что отпечатки массив - их может быть несколько

Comment: Все заработало...спасибо огромное

Answer (score 1):

Приложения могут подписываться разными ключами. Когда приложение устанавливается после компиляции в Android Studio создается тоже apk файл и с него происходит сама установка. То, что ты сделал по инструкции - это debug ключ и API от vk.com будет только работать в приложении, если оно было установлено прямо из Android Studio. Чтобы API работало на релизных apk файлах, которые будут распространяться - нужно так же добавить еще релизный ключ на сайте. Получить его можно почти так же, единственное, что нужно в параметрах для командной строки указать конкретное хранилище ключей, которым будет подписываться приложение.